# VB.NET How do I apply decimal formatting to a specific column in a Gridview?

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, floating-point, decimal

How do I apply decimal formatting to a specific column in a Gridview?

eg 83.7837837837838 is being populated from SQL, how do I convert it to 83.8.

I only want to apply this to one column as other columns are integers, so this won't be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using the [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property. For example:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ListPrice" 
            HeaderText="ListPrice" 
            SortExpression="ListPrice"
            DataFormatString="{0:F1}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You could also use [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) where you have more control:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // assuming you are using BoundFields and
        // the column which you want to format is the first
        // if you are using TemplateFields use e.Row.FindControl("ControlID") to find your controls
        var row = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem;
        decimal price = (decimal)row["ListPrice"];
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = price.ToString("F1");
    }
}
```

Edit: Here the VB.NET version:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As [Object], e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' assuming you are using BoundFields and                                                   '
        ' the column which you want to format is the first                                         '
        ' if you are using TemplateFields use e.Row.FindControl("ControlID") to find your controls '
        Dim row = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
        Dim price As Decimal = CDec(row("ListPrice"))
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = price.ToString("F1")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use  **BoundField.DataFormatString** Property, For solving your problem and to get proper knowledge check this [Microsoft Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Hope it works for you.